# How to auto update a table using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp-classic

I need to use AJAX to request a random string of 10 numbers from an asp page, delimited by "||" and then display the results on a table.

However the table can only show the top 10 results, and as a new row is added the bottom row should be bumped.

I have done this but what i dont know is how i will use AJAX to automatically update the results on the table, without me having to manually refresh.

im not to use jQuery

Comment: You don't necessarily have to use jQuery, but please do yourself a favor and use _any_ javascript framework; you can't imagine what kind of problems you'll get with cross-browser compat if you want to do an ajax request and more than simple DOM manipulation

Comment: Are you asking how to use AJAX without jQuery, or how to make it automatically?

Comment: I have one string off 100 random numbers seperated by "||". I split these up and display them in a 10x10 table. I have a function that requests another string of 10 numbers from an ASP page and appends it to the start of the string, which bumps off the numbers at then end of the string from being displayed on the table.

I'd like to know how i can get AJAX to request the new string every second (by calling the asp page), and automatically updating the table every second. 

I hope this makes sense

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you *really* don't want to use a JS framework, you'll have to look to the [`XMLHttpRequest()` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest). To poll on a regular interval, you use the good-ol' [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) and for DOM manipulation start out with [getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById) and [Node.lastChild property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.lastChild).

Start playing around with those and ask some specific questions if you get stuck.